# Centering multiple canvas layers in tikz 3D

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot, tikz-3d

So I am trying to recreate the attached image exactly. But for the upper red ring, I can't seem to have it centered well. I have tried multiple modifications, but it just does not want to center itself like the black dashed ring. Please help.
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy,bending}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{112}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,line cap=round,>=stealth,scale=0.75]
\begin{scope}[rotate=9]
\draw[dashed,thick,canvas is xy plane at z=0] circle[radius=2.75cm];
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[roll=9]
\draw[dashed,thick,red,canvas is xy plane at z=2] circle[radius=1.75cm];
\end{scope}
\draw[-Latex] (0,0,0) coordinate (O) -- (7,0,0) node[pos=1.2] {$x$}; 
\draw[-Latex,rotate around={8:(O)}] (O) -- (0,4,0) node[pos=1.1] {$y$};
\draw[-Latex] (O) -- (0,0,4) node[pos=1.1] {$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the main problem in your code is the line

```tex
\begin{scope}[roll=9]
```

This produces an error an doesn't compile. I suppose you want to `rotate` like in the other `scope`:

```
\begin{scope}[rotate=9]
```

If you somehow can get a compilation of the code (I'm thinking in Overleaf, but I don't know if it is possible), the black circle will be rotated but not the red one. They are centered but have different rotations around the z-axis, and I think this is the problem you want to solve.

Anyway, you don't need to rotate the circles if you choose your 3d view. For that you can define the axes (as I did) or use `tikz-3dplot` package, `perspective` Ti*k*Z library,...

Here is a customizable code and almost free of packages and libraries. I only use `3d` library for the options

```tex
canvas is xy plane at z=...
```

but I think you'll want to include `arrows.meta` too, if you need more arrow styles.

```tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}  % for "canvas is..." options
\tikzset{my circle/.style={dashed,thick,canvas is xy plane at z=#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,
                    x={(-0.4cm,-0.4cm)}, y={(1cm,0cm)},z={(0cm,1cm)}] % <--- 3d axes
% dimensions
\def\br{2.5}   % big radius
\def\lr{1.75}  % little radius
\def\ch{2}     % circles height
\def\na{8}     % number of arrows
\pgfmathsetmacro\aa{360/\na} % angle between arrows
% origin
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
% axes
\draw[-latex] (O)      -- (6,0,0) node[below] {$x$}; 
\draw[-latex] (O)      -- (0,4,0) node[right] {$y$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0,-4) -- (0,0,4) node[above] {$z$};
% circles
\draw[my circle=-\ch,blue] circle[radius=\lr];
\draw[my circle= 0]        circle[radius=\br];
\draw[my circle= \ch,red]  circle[radius=\lr];
% arrows
\foreach\i in {1,...,\na}
{
  \draw[red ,thick,-latex] (O) -- ({\lr*cos(\i*\aa)},{\lr*sin(\i*\aa)}, \ch);
  \draw[blue,thick,-latex] (O) -- ({\lr*cos(\i*\aa)},{\lr*sin(\i*\aa)},-\ch);
}
\draw[thick,-latex]  (O) -- (0,\br,0) node[midway,above] {$\mathbf{L}$};
% aux lines and \hbar
\foreach\i in {-1,1}
  \draw[gray,dashed] (0,\lr,\i*\ch) --++ (0,-\lr,0) node[black,left] {$\ifnum\i<0-\fi\hbar$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]